# Simple HTML and FlaskWTForm with date and timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Here I have created flaskwtform which will accpet two dates which is working fine. I want datetime picker should give me complete date with d/m-y format with UTC timestamp.

> flaskWTForm.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from datetime import date
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateTimeField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='secretkey'

class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    startdate = DateField('From Date')
    todate = DateField('To Date')


@app.route('/dateExample',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    forms = TestForm()
    if forms.validate_on_submit():
        return 'From Date is : {} To Date is : {}'.format(forms.startdate.data, forms.todate.data)
    return render_template('dateExample.html',form=forms)

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

> [dateExample.html]

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> Flask WFForm </h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('.index')}}">
 {{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.startdate.label }}
   {{ form.startdate }}
{{ form.todate.label }}
   {{ form.todate }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

This worked for me:

forms.py

```
class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    startdate = DateField('From Date')
    todate = DateField('To Date')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

test.html

```
<html>
<body>
{% if result %}
<h1>{{ result }}</h1>
{% else %}
<h1> Flask WFForm </h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
 {{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.startdate.label }}
   {{ form.startdate }}
{{ form.todate.label }}
   {{ form.todate }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    form = TestForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        result = 'From Date is : {} To Date is : {}'.format(form.startdate.data.strftime('%d-%m-%y'), form.todate.data.strftime('%d-%m-%y'))
        return render_template('test.html', form=form, result=result)

    return render_template('test.html', form=form)
```

Comment: You are right format='%Y-%m-%d' . But when I am giving format='%d/%m/%y' It is not working and Not showing any output.